# Ubuntu Server no syslog append and can't ssh with Intel AX101

Tags: server, kernel, network-manager

My device is Beelink EQ12 and installed Ubuntu server 22.04.2 with HWE to use as a server.

And I install docker to run some service.

But when the server run for 2days around, I can't ssh to the server, but the power light is on. only if put the power off and restart the serer, I can use ssh again.

After I login, I tail the `/var/log/syslog` , find some error about network-adapter.

```bash
May 16 13:13:14 node2 kernel: [192337.360850] vethce45ae9: renamed from eth0
May 16 13:13:14 node2 networkd-dispatcher[635]: WARNING:Unknown index 6418 seen, reloading interface list
May 16 13:13:14 node2 systemd-udevd[661233]: Using default interface naming scheme 'v249'.
May 16 13:13:14 node2 systemd-networkd[601]: veth3946a6b: Link DOWN
May 16 13:13:14 node2 kernel: [192337.424350] br-9d0f0fc16682: port 10(veth3946a6b) entered disabled state
May 16 13:13:14 node2 kernel: [192337.425740] device veth3946a6b left promiscuous mode
May 16 13:13:14 node2 kernel: [192337.425751] br-9d0f0fc16682: port 10(veth3946a6b) entered disabled state
May 16 13:13:14 node2 networkd-dispatcher[635]: ERROR:Unknown interface index 6418 seen even after reload
May 16 13:13:14 node2 networkd-dispatcher[635]: WARNING:Unknown index 6418 seen, reloading interface list
May 16 13:13:14 node2 networkd-dispatcher[635]: ERROR:Unknown interface index 6418 seen even after reload
May 16 13:13:14 node2 systemd[1]: run-docker-netns-b8ef1c3280dc.mount: Deactivated successfully.
May 16 13:13:14 node2 systemd[1]: var-lib-docker-overlay2-c57f032487134616e75dd8305d77c0c8c15f416ee1c0abcaa0553069231eece5-merged.mount: Deactivated successfully.
May 16 13:14:13 node2 systemd-udevd[661400]: Using default interface naming scheme 'v249'.
May 16 13:14:13 node2 networkd-dispatcher[635]: WARNING:Unknown index 6420 seen, reloading interface list
May 16 13:14:13 node2 kernel: [192397.234618] br-9d0f0fc16682: port 10(veth646c6f8) entered blocking state
May 16 13:14:13 node2 kernel: [192397.234624] br-9d0f0fc16682: port 10(veth646c6f8) entered disabled state
May 16 13:14:13 node2 kernel: [192397.236247] device veth646c6f8 entered promiscuous mode
May 16 13:14:13 node2 systemd-networkd[601]: veth646c6f8: Link UP
May 16 13:14:13 node2 systemd-udevd[661401]: Using default interface naming scheme 'v249'.
May 16 13:14:13 node2 dockerd[737]: time="2023-05-16T13:14:13.893665981+08:00" level=info msg="No non-localhost DNS nameservers are left in resolv.conf. Using default external servers: [nameserver 8.8.8.8 nameserver 8.8.4.4]"
May 16 13:14:13 node2 dockerd[737]: time="2023-05-16T13:14:13.893691304+08:00" level=info msg="IPv6 enabled; Adding default IPv6 external servers: [nameserver 2001:4860:4860::8888 nameserver 2001:4860:4860::8844]"
May 16 13:14:13 node2 containerd[649]: time="2023-05-16T13:14:13.947770816+08:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.event.v1.publisher\"..." runtime=io.containerd.runc.v2 type=io.containerd.event.v1
May 16 13:14:13 node2 containerd[649]: time="2023-05-16T13:14:13.947850484+08:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.internal.v1.shutdown\"..." runtime=io.containerd.runc.v2 type=io.containerd.internal.v1
May 16 13:14:13 node2 containerd[649]: time="2023-05-16T13:14:13.947872996+08:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.ttrpc.v1.task\"..." runtime=io.containerd.runc.v2 type=io.containerd.ttrpc.v1
May 16 13:14:13 node2 containerd[649]: time="2023-05-16T13:14:13.948141641+08:00" level=info msg="starting signal loop" namespace=moby path=/run/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v2.task/moby/8a189c014fdca08f012c681f07fd283dedc716e8a24cfd21ea0e8bc78927cca9 pid=661466 runtime=io.containerd.runc.v2
May 16 13:14:13 node2 systemd[1]: Started libcontainer container 8a189c014fdca08f012c681f07fd283dedc716e8a24cfd21ea0e8bc78927cca9.
May 16 13:14:14 node2 kernel: [192397.488944] eth0: renamed from veth0a0601c
May 16 13:14:14 node2 systemd-networkd[601]: veth646c6f8: Gained carrier
May 16 13:14:14 node2 kernel: [192397.508410] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): veth646c6f8: link becomes ready
May 16 13:14:14 node2 kernel: [192397.508489] br-9d0f0fc16682: port 10(veth646c6f8) entered blocking state
May 16 13:14:14 node2 kernel: [192397.508497] br-9d0f0fc16682: port 10(veth646c6f8) entered forwarding state
May 16 13:14:14 node2 systemd[1]: docker-8a189c014fdca08f012c681f07fd283dedc716e8a24cfd21ea0e8bc78927cca9.scope: Deactivated successfully.
May 16 13:14:14 node2 containerd[649]: time="2023-05-16T13:14:14.193335024+08:00" level=warning msg="error from *cgroupsv2.Manager.EventChan" error="failed to add inotify watch for \"/sys/fs/cgroup/system.slice/docker-8a189c014fdca08f012c681f07fd283dedc716e8a24cfd21ea0e8bc78927cca9.scope/memory.events\": no such file or directory"
May 16 13:14:14 node2 dockerd[737]: time="2023-05-16T13:14:14.208279955+08:00" level=info msg="ignoring event" container=8a189c014fdca08f012c681f07fd283dedc716e8a24cfd21ea0e8bc78927cca9 module=libcontainerd namespace=moby topic=/tasks/delete type="*events.TaskDelete"
May 16 13:14:14 node2 containerd[649]: time="2023-05-16T13:14:14.208438575+08:00" level=info msg="shim disconnected" id=8a189c014fdca08f012c681f07fd283dedc716e8a24cfd21ea0e8bc78927cca9
May 16 13:14:14 node2 containerd[649]: time="2023-05-16T13:14:14.208499095+08:00" level=warning msg="cleaning up after shim disconnected" id=8a189c014fdca08f012c681f07fd283dedc716e8a24cfd21ea0e8bc78927cca9 namespace=moby
May 16 13:14:14 node2 containerd[649]: time="2023-05-16T13:14:14.208515690+08:00" level=info msg="cleaning up dead shim"
May 16 13:14:14 node2 containerd[649]: time="2023-05-16T13:14:14.216383772+08:00" level=warning msg="cleanup warnings time=\"2023-05-16T13:14:14+08:00\" level=info msg=\"starting signal loop\" namespace=moby pid=661541 runtime=io.containerd.runc.v2\n"
May 16 13:14:14 node2 systemd-networkd[601]: veth646c6f8: Lost carrier
May 16 13:14:14 node2 kernel: [192397.705518] br-9d0f0fc16682: port 10(veth646c6f8) entered disabled state
May 16 13:14:14 node2 kernel: [192397.705611] veth0a0601c: renamed from eth0
May 16 13:14:14 node2 networkd-dispatcher[635]: WARNING:Unknown index 6420 seen, reloading interface list
May 16 13:14:14 node2 systemd-udevd[661415]: Using default interface naming scheme 'v249'.
May 16 13:14:14 node2 systemd-networkd[601]: veth646c6f8: Link DOWN
May 16 13:14:14 node2 kernel: [192397.764128] br-9d0f0fc16682: port 10(veth646c6f8) entered disabled state
May 16 13:14:14 node2 kernel: [192397.765667] device veth646c6f8 left promiscuous mode
May 16 13:14:14 node2 kernel: [192397.765684] br-9d0f0fc16682: port 10(veth646c6f8) entered disabled state
May 16 13:14:14 node2 networkd-dispatcher[635]: ERROR:Unknown interface index 6420 seen even after reload
May 16 13:14:14 node2 networkd-dispatcher[635]: WARNING:Unknown index 6420 seen, reloading interface list
May 16 13:14:14 node2 networkd-dispatcher[635]: ERROR:Unknown interface index 6420 seen even after reload
May 16 13:14:14 node2 systemd[1]: run-docker-netns-7bcd239c0063.mount: Deactivated successfully.
May 16 13:14:14 node2 systemd[1]: var-lib-docker-overlay2-c57f032487134616e75dd8305d77c0c8c15f416ee1c0abcaa0553069231eece5-merged.mount: Deactivated successfully.
May 16 13:15:14 node2 systemd-udevd[661590]: Using default interface naming scheme 'v249'.
May 16 13:15:14 node2 kernel: [192457.579641] br-9d0f0fc16682: port 10(veth3ec3b05) entered blocking state
May 16 13:15:14 node2 kernel: [192457.579646] br-9d0f0fc16682: port 10(veth3ec3b05) entered disabled state
May 16 13:15:14 node2 kernel: [192457.579764] device veth3ec3b05 entered promiscuous mode
May 16 13:15:14 node2 networkd-dispatcher[635]: WARNING:Unknown index 6422 seen, reloading interface list
May 16 13:15:14 node2 systemd-udevd[661591]: Using default interface naming scheme 'v249'.
May 16 13:15:14 node2 systemd-networkd[601]: veth3ec3b05: Link UP
May 16 13:15:14 node2 dockerd[737]: time="2023-05-16T13:15:14.235521100+08:00" level=info msg="No non-localhost DNS nameservers are left in resolv.conf. Using default external servers: [nameserver 8.8.8.8 nameserver 8.8.4.4]"
May 16 13:15:14 node2 dockerd[737]: time="2023-05-16T13:15:14.235545772+08:00" level=info msg="IPv6 enabled; Adding default IPv6 external servers: [nameserver 2001:4860:4860::8888 nameserver 2001:4860:4860::8844]"
May 16 13:15:14 node2 containerd[649]: time="2023-05-16T13:15:14.288899504+08:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.event.v1.publisher\"..." runtime=io.containerd.runc.v2 type=io.containerd.event.v1
May 16 13:15:14 node2 containerd[649]: time="2023-05-16T13:15:14.289001239+08:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.internal.v1.shutdown\"..." runtime=io.containerd.runc.v2 type=io.containerd.internal.v1
May 16 13:15:14 node2 containerd[649]: time="2023-05-16T13:15:14.289023887+08:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.ttrpc.v1.task\"..." runtime=io.containerd.runc.v2 type=io.containerd.ttrpc.v1
May 16 13:15:14 node2 containerd[649]: time="2023-05-16T13:15:14.289349297+08:00" level=info msg="starting signal loop" namespace=moby path=/run/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v2.task/moby/8a189c014fdca08f012c681f07fd283dedc716e8a24cfd21ea0e8bc78927cca9 pid=661657 runtime=io.containerd.runc.v2
May 16 13:15:14 node2 systemd[1]: Started libcontainer container 8a189c014fdca08f012c681f07fd283dedc716e8a24cfd21ea0e8bc78927cca9.
May 16 13:15:14 node2 kernel: [192457.841633] eth0: renamed from veth86bb5ea
May 16 13:15:14 node2 systemd-networkd[601]: veth3ec3b05: Gained carrier
May 16 13:15:14 node2 kernel: [192457.857501] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): veth3ec3b05: link becomes ready
May 16 13:15:14 node2 kernel: [192457.857602] br-9d0f0fc16682: port 10(veth3ec3b05) entered blocking state
May 16 13:15:14 node2 kernel: [192457.857614] br-9d0f0fc16682: port 10(veth3ec3b05) entered forwarding state
May 16 13:15:14 node2 systemd[1]: docker-8a189c014fdca08f012c681f07fd283dedc716e8a24cfd21ea0e8bc78927cca9.scope: Deactivated successfully.
May 16 13:15:14 node2 containerd[649]: time="2023-05-16T13:15:14.540386809+08:00" level=warning msg="error from *cgroupsv2.Manager.EventChan" error="failed to add inotify watch for \"/sys/fs/cgroup/system.slice/docker-8a189c014fdca08f012c681f07fd283dedc716e8a24cfd21ea0e8bc78927cca9.scope/memory.events\": no such file or directory"
May 16 13:15:14 node2 containerd[649]: time="2023-05-16T13:15:14.559223887+08:00" level=info msg="shim disconnected" id=8a189c014fdca08f012c681f07fd283dedc716e8a24cfd21ea0e8bc78927cca9
May 16 13:15:14 node2 containerd[649]: time="2023-05-16T13:15:14.559290269+08:00" level=warning msg="cleaning up after shim disconnected" id=8a189c014fdca08f012c681f07fd283dedc716e8a24cfd21ea0e8bc78927cca9 namespace=moby
May 16 13:15:14 node2 containerd[649]: time="2023-05-16T13:15:14.559309501+08:00" level=info msg="cleaning up dead shim"
May 16 13:15:14 node2 dockerd[737]: time="2023-05-16T13:15:14.559260777+08:00" level=info msg="ignoring event" container=8a189c014fdca08f012c681f07fd283dedc716e8a24cfd21ea0e8bc78927cca9 module=libcontainerd namespace=moby topic=/tasks/delete type="*events.TaskDelete"
May 16 13:15:14 node2 containerd[649]: time="2023-05-16T13:15:14.568911911+08:00" level=warning msg="cleanup warnings time=\"2023-05-16T13:15:14+08:00\" level=info msg=\"starting signal loop\" namespace=moby pid=661731 runtime=io.containerd.runc.v2\n"
May 16 13:15:14 node2 systemd-networkd[601]: veth3ec3b05: Lost carrier
May 16 13:15:14 node2 kernel: [192458.057983] br-9d0f0fc16682: port 10(veth3ec3b05) entered disabled state
May 16 13:15:14 node2 kernel: [192458.058090] veth86bb5ea: renamed from eth0
May 16 13:15:14 node2 networkd-dispatcher[635]: WARNING:Unknown index 6422 seen, reloading interface list
May 16 13:15:14 node2 systemd-udevd[661603]: Using default interface naming scheme 'v249'.
May 16 13:15:14 node2 systemd-networkd[601]: veth3ec3b05: Link DOWN
May 16 13:15:14 node2 kernel: [192458.104828] br-9d0f0fc16682: port 10(veth3ec3b05) entered disabled state
May 16 13:15:14 node2 kernel: [192458.106105] device veth3ec3b05 left promiscuous mode
May 16 13:15:14 node2 kernel: [192458.106120] br-9d0f0fc16682: port 10(veth3ec3b05) entered disabled state
May 16 13:15:14 node2 networkd-dispatcher[635]: ERROR:Unknown interface index 6422 seen even after reload
May 16 13:15:14 node2 networkd-dispatcher[635]: WARNING:Unknown index 6422 seen, reloading interface list
May 16 13:15:14 node2 networkd-dispatcher[635]: ERROR:Unknown interface index 6422 seen even after reload
May 16 13:15:14 node2 systemd[1]: run-docker-netns-1d235f8d7a68.mount: Deactivated successfully.
May 16 13:15:15 node2 systemd[1]: var-lib-docker-overlay2-c57f032487134616e75dd8305d77c0c8c15f416ee1c0abcaa0553069231eece5-merged.mount: Deactivated successfully.
May 16 13:16:14 node2 networkd-dispatcher[635]: WARNING:Unknown index 6424 seen, reloading interface list
May 16 13:16:14 node2 systemd-udevd[661765]: Using default interface naming scheme 'v249'.
May 16 13:16:14 node2 systemd-networkd[601]: veth9c01401: Link UP
May 16 13:16:14 node2 kernel: [192517.931082] br-9d0f0fc16682: port 10(veth9c01401) entered blocking state
May 16 13:16:14 node2 kernel: [192517.931088] br-9d0f0fc16682: port 10(veth9c01401) entered disabled state
May 16 13:16:14 node2 kernel: [192517.931150] device veth9c01401 entered promiscuous mode
May 16 13:16:14 node2 systemd-udevd[661768]: Using default interface naming scheme 'v249'.
May 16 13:16:14 node2 dockerd[737]: time="2023-05-16T13:16:14.587266184+08:00" level=info msg="No non-localhost DNS nameservers are left in resolv.conf. Using default external servers: [nameserver 8.8.8.8 nameserver 8.8.4.4]"
May 16 13:16:14 node2 dockerd[737]: time="2023-05-16T13:16:14.587291336+08:00" level=info msg="IPv6 enabled; Adding default IPv6 external servers: [nameserver 2001:4860:4860::8888 nameserver 2001:4860:4860::8844]"
May 16 13:16:14 node2 containerd[649]: time="2023-05-16T13:16:14.640428459+08:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.event.v1.publisher\"..." runtime=io.containerd.runc.v2 type=io.containerd.event.v1
May 16 13:16:14 node2 containerd[649]: time="2023-05-16T13:16:14.640498408+08:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.internal.v1.shutdown\"..." runtime=io.containerd.runc.v2 type=io.containerd.internal.v1
May 16 13:16:14 node2 containerd[649]: time="2023-05-16T13:16:14.640515469+08:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.ttrpc.v1.task\"..." runtime=io.containerd.runc.v2 type=io.containerd.ttrpc.v1
May 16 13:16:14 node2 containerd[649]: time="2023-05-16T13:16:14.640671576+08:00" level=info msg="starting signal loop" namespace=moby path=/run/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v2.task/moby/8a189c014fdca08f012c681f07fd283dedc716e8a24cfd21ea0e8bc78927cca9 pid=661830 runtime=io.containerd.runc.v2
May 16 13:16:14 node2 systemd[1]: run-docker-runtime\x2drunc-moby-8a189c014fdca08f012c681f07fd283dedc716e8a24cfd21ea0e8bc78927cca9-runc.jOUMym.mount: Deactivated successfully.
May 16 13:16:14 node2 systemd[1]: Started libcontainer container 8a189c014fdca08f012c681f07fd283dedc716e8a24cfd21ea0e8bc78927cca9.
May 16 13:16:14 node2 kernel: [192518.195087] eth0: renamed from veth3c96a88
May 16 13:16:14 node2 systemd-networkd[601]: veth9c01401: Gained carrier
May 16 13:16:14 node2 kernel: [192518.226491] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): veth9c01401: link becomes ready
May 16 13:16:14 node2 kernel: [192518.226603] br-9d0f0fc16682: port 10(veth9c01401) entered blocking state
May 16 13:16:14 node2 kernel: [192518.226615] br-9d0f0fc16682: port 10(veth9c01401) entered forwarding state
May 16 13:16:14 node2 systemd[1]: docker-8a189c014fdca08f012c681f07fd283dedc716e8a24cfd21ea0e8bc78927cca9.scope: Deactivated successfully.
May 16 13:16:14 node2 dockerd[737]: time="2023-05-16T13:16:14.923750850+08:00" level=info msg="ignoring event" container=8a189c014fdca08f012c681f07fd283dedc716e8a24cfd21ea0e8bc78927cca9 module=libcontainerd namespace=moby topic=/tasks/delete type="*events.TaskDelete"
May 16 13:16:14 node2 containerd[649]: time="2023-05-16T13:16:14.924562530+08:00" level=info msg="shim disconnected" id=8a189c014fdca08f012c681f07fd283dedc716e8a24cfd21ea0e8bc78927cca9
May 16 13:16:14 node2 containerd[649]: time="2023-05-16T13:16:14.924628573+08:00" level=warning msg="cleaning up after shim disconnected" id=8a189c014fdca08f012c681f07fd283dedc716e8a24cfd21ea0e8bc78927cca9 namespace=moby
May 16 13:16:14 node2 containerd[649]: time="2023-05-16T13:16:14.924647337+08:00" level=info msg="cleaning up dead shim"
May 16 13:16:14 node2 containerd[649]: time="2023-05-16T13:16:14.932499412+08:00" level=warning msg="cleanup warnings time=\"2023-05-16T13:16:14+08:00\" level=info msg=\"starting signal loop\" namespace=moby pid=661908 runtime=io.containerd.runc.v2\n"
May 16 13:16:15 node2 systemd-networkd[601]: veth9c01401: Lost carrier
May 16 13:16:15 node2 kernel: [192518.431565] br-9d0f0fc16682: port 10(veth9c01401) entered disabled state
May 16 13:16:15 node2 kernel: [192518.431659] veth3c96a88: renamed from eth0
May 16 13:16:15 node2 networkd-dispatcher[635]: WARNING:Unknown index 6424 seen, reloading interface list
May 16 13:16:15 node2 systemd-udevd[661776]: Using default interface naming scheme 'v249'.
May 16 13:16:15 node2 systemd-networkd[601]: veth9c01401: Link DOWN
May 16 13:16:15 node2 kernel: [192518.477097] br-9d0f0fc16682: port 10(veth9c01401) entered disabled state
May 16 13:16:15 node2 kernel: [192518.477780] device veth9c01401 left promiscuous mode
May 16 13:16:15 node2 kernel: [192518.477787] br-9d0f0fc16682: port 10(veth9c01401) entered disabled state
May 16 13:16:15 node2 systemd[1]: run-docker-netns-03a754f68d2a.mount: Deactivated successfully.
May 16 13:16:15 node2 systemd[1]: var-lib-docker-overlay2-c57f032487134616e75dd8305d77c0c8c15f416ee1c0abcaa0553069231eece5-merged.mount: Deactivated successfully.
May 16 13:17:01 node2 CRON[661951]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
May 16 13:17:14 node2 systemd-udevd[661959]: Using default interface naming scheme 'v249'.
May 16 13:17:14 node2 kernel: [192578.296511] br-9d0f0fc16682: port 10(veth6baf850) entered blocking state
May 16 13:17:14 node2 kernel: [192578.296517] br-9d0f0fc16682: port 10(veth6baf850) entered disabled state
May 16 13:17:14 node2 kernel: [192578.296650] device veth6baf850 entered promiscuous mode
May 16 13:17:14 node2 networkd-dispatcher[635]: WARNING:Unknown index 6426 seen, reloading interface list
May 16 13:17:14 node2 systemd-udevd[661960]: Using default interface naming scheme 'v249'.
May 16 13:17:14 node2 systemd-networkd[601]: veth6baf850: Link UP
May 16 13:17:14 node2 dockerd[737]: time="2023-05-16T13:17:14.952651243+08:00" level=info msg="No non-localhost DNS nameservers are left in resolv.conf. Using default external servers: [nameserver 8.8.8.8 nameserver 8.8.4.4]"
May 16 13:17:14 node2 dockerd[737]: time="2023-05-16T13:17:14.952678728+08:00" level=info msg="IPv6 enabled; Adding default IPv6 external servers: [nameserver 2001:4860:4860::8888 nameserver 2001:4860:4860::8844]"
May 16 13:17:15 node2 containerd[649]: time="2023-05-16T13:17:15.009611913+08:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.event.v1.publisher\"..." runtime=io.containerd.runc.v2 type=io.containerd.event.v1
May 16 13:17:15 node2 containerd[649]: time="2023-05-16T13:17:15.009698122+08:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.internal.v1.shutdown\"..." runtime=io.containerd.runc.v2 type=io.containerd.internal.v1
May 16 13:17:15 node2 containerd[649]: time="2023-05-16T13:17:15.009718330+08:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.ttrpc.v1.task\"..." runtime=io.containerd.runc.v2 type=io.containerd.ttrpc.v1
May 16 13:17:15 node2 containerd[649]: time="2023-05-16T13:17:15.009913646+08:00" level=info msg="starting signal loop" namespace=moby path=/run/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v2.task/moby/8a189c014fdca08f012c681f07fd283dedc716e8a24cfd21ea0e8bc78927cca9 pid=662029 runtime=io.containerd.runc.v2
May 16 13:17:15 node2 systemd[1]: Started libcontainer container 8a189c014fdca08f012c681f07fd283dedc716e8a24cfd21ea0e8bc78927cca9.
May 16 13:17:15 node2 kernel: [192578.566541] eth0: renamed from vethef82365
May 16 13:17:15 node2 systemd-networkd[601]: veth6baf850: Gained carrier
May 16 13:17:15 node2 kernel: [192578.582068] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): veth6baf850: link becomes ready
May 16 13:17:15 node2 kernel: [192578.582162] br-9d0f0fc16682: port 10(veth6baf850) entered blocking state
May 16 13:17:15 node2 kernel: [192578.582171] br-9d0f0fc16682: port 10(veth6baf850) entered forwarding state
May 16 13:17:15 node2 systemd[1]: docker-8a189c014fdca08f012c681f07fd283dedc716e8a24cfd21ea0e8bc78927cca9.scope: Deactivated successfully.
May 16 13:17:15 node2 dockerd[737]: time="2023-05-16T13:17:15.281339171+08:00" level=info msg="ignoring event" container=8a189c014fdca08f012c681f07fd283dedc716e8a24cfd21ea0e8bc78927cca9 module=libcontainerd namespace=moby topic=/tasks/delete type="*events.TaskDelete"
May 16 13:17:15 node2 containerd[649]: time="2023-05-16T13:17:15.282063287+08:00" level=info msg="shim disconnected" id=8a189c014fdca08f012c681f07fd283dedc716e8a24cfd21ea0e8bc78927cca9
May 16 13:17:15 node2 containerd[649]: time="2023-05-16T13:17:15.282107125+08:00" level=warning msg="cleaning up after shim disconnected" id=8a189c014fdca08f012c681f07fd283dedc716e8a24cfd21ea0e8bc78927cca9 namespace=moby
May 16 13:17:15 node2 containerd[649]: time="2023-05-16T13:17:15.282118790+08:00" level=info msg="cleaning up dead shim"
May 16 13:17:15 node2 containerd[649]: time="2023-05-16T13:17:15.288597822+08:00" level=warning msg="cleanup warnings time=\"2023-05-16T13:17:15+08:00\" level=info msg=\"starting signal loop\" namespace=moby pid=662107 runtime=io.containerd.runc.v2\n"
May 16 13:17:15 node2 systemd-networkd[601]: veth6baf850: Lost carrier
May 16 13:17:15 node2 kernel: [192578.767311] br-9d0f0fc16682: port 10(veth6baf850) entered disabled state
May 16 13:17:15 node2 kernel: [192578.767410] vethef82365: renamed from eth0
May 16 13:17:15 node2 networkd-dispatcher[635]: WARNING:Unknown index 6426 seen, reloading interface list
May 16 13:17:15 node2 systemd-udevd[661969]: Using default interface naming scheme 'v249'.
May 16 13:17:15 node2 systemd-networkd[601]: veth6baf850: Link DOWN
May 16 13:17:15 node2 kernel: [192578.826076] br-9d0f0fc16682: port 10(veth6baf850) entered disabled state
May 16 13:17:15 node2 kernel: [192578.827829] device veth6baf850 left promiscuous mode
May 16 13:17:15 node2 kernel: [192578.827840] br-9d0f0fc16682: port 10(veth6baf850) entered disabled state
May 16 13:17:15 node2 networkd-dispatcher[635]: ERROR:Unknown interface index 6426 seen even after reload
May 16 13:17:15 node2 networkd-dispatcher[635]: WARNING:Unknown index 6426 seen, reloading interface list
May 16 13:17:15 node2 networkd-dispatcher[635]: ERROR:Unknown interface index 6426 seen even after reload
May 16 13:17:15 node2 systemd[1]: run-docker-netns-26a0e9ac232e.mount: Deactivated successfully.
May 16 13:17:15 node2 systemd[1]: var-lib-docker-overlay2-c57f032487134616e75dd8305d77c0c8c15f416ee1c0abcaa0553069231eece5-merged.mount: Deactivated successfully.
```

I wonder does those happen because the network card is **Intel® Wi-Fi 6 AX101** ?

> ps: because is server so there are no monitor to use,when server frezzing.

Comment: I've got simular problems, did you ever fix this?